# Using pushState after a successfull ajax get request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coffeescript, pushstate

I am trying to implement the `pushState` method, but cannot get it to work properly. The `history.pushState` line gets triggered without performing the desired change of browser window URL. No error messages are appearing in the console.

The problem is probably the last `@href` argument, because if I replace it with something like `"#test"`, the browser window URL changes to `/#test`.

What am I missing here?:

```
paramsBtn = $(".reorder-orders")
paramsBtn.off "click"
paramsBtn.click (e) ->
    el = $(e.currentTarget)
    reorder = el.attr("reorder")

    $.ajax
        type: "get"
        dataType: "script"
        data:
            view: reorder
        url: "/api/orders/reorder_orders"
        success: (data, status, xhr) ->
            history.pushState null, "", @href
            false

        error: (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
            console.log "Error while organizing"
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.log` to check the value that `@href` is assigned to ?

Comment: Yes, it is just `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by `@href` you probably want to refer to the button's href attribute. You cannot access to `this` anymore in `$.ajax`'s callback function, so you should store what you need in a variable before.

Right after `reorder = el.attr("reorder")`, add `href = @href`

Then update your `pushState` line like this: `history.pushState null, "", href`